# Translate toolkit : csv2po plural conversion is not formatted properly

Tags: debian, plural

I use csv2po with a template file. The plural strings are not formatted properly.

The expected result :

```
#: /fr
msgid "hour"
msgid_plural "hours"
msgstr[0] "heure"
msgstr[1] "heures"
```

The actual result :

```
#: /fr
msgid "hour"
msgid_plural "hours"
msgstr[0] h
e
u
r
e
msgstr[1] h
e
u
r
e
s
```

My environment : debian wheezy 32bits.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the Gettext Component of Drupal 8.